# Validation of textbox with numbers using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to prevent or validate  the user entering numbers 6 digits with range (eg: 100000) and two decimal digits in a textbox using javascript ?
I m using `onkeypress` event in my textbox my code is:

```
      var txtBudget = document.getElementById('MainContent_txtBudget');
        txtBudget.addEventListener('keypress', function (evt)
        {  
        var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
        if (!/^\d{0,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(value)) 
           {   
             evt.preventDefault();
           }
       },
 false);​
```

Comment: I suppose
[this article][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

will help you.

Comment: thanks .. also it should allow only digits not any other alphabets or special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HTML5 `input type='number'` there is no need to use javascript for this validation. Say for example you want a number between 100,000.00 and 200,000 with two decimal digits, use this in your HTML

```
Number: <input type="number" name="number" min="100000.00" max="200000" step='0.01'/>
```

Comment: IMO W3Schools is a horrible site, that frequently gives examples using worst practices (see http://w3fools.com/). There's an equivalent page on MDN (generally a much better source of information) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input. Good answer though, +1

Comment: Ohh I never realized and always considered it a reliable source. Thanks for pointing out. I have removed the reference from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why not to use RegularExpression control from Asp.net toolbox. Check out this sample:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
 runat="server" ValidationExpression="^\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$" ErrorMessage="Only 6 digit numbers allowed"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

And if my ValidationExpression is wrong visit this link for your choice: [Find Any Regular Expression](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 0):

'i guess you want something like this ,
call this function `onKeyPress` Event of your textbox

```
 function test()
    {
      var obj=document.getElementById('textbox1');
      if(obj.value)
      {
            if(isNaN(obj.value)) 
            {
               alert('Please enter only numbers');
                return;
            }

      }
    }
```

Comment: you modified your question till i submitted my answer. but still you customize this and use.

Comment: thanks pranav.. would like to hav validation in textbox with allowing only digits